# IE says javascript function is undefined, but it works in Chrome OK

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I have a wepage that contains a link - to open a new window showing a YouTube video.  It works fine in Chrome, but in IE it doesnt work.  The IE console says: *SCRIPT5009: 'open_win' is undefined*    (I'm using IE11)

In the head section I have:

```
function open_win(url)
   {
   new_window = open('','video','width=500,height=390,menubar=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes');
   // open new document 
    new_window.document.open();
    // Text of the new document 
    new_window.document.write("<html><head></head><body style='background-color:'black';margin-top:0; margin-right:0; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:0;'>");
    new_window.document.write("<iframe width='560' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/-linkRedacted-' frameborder='0' allow='autoplay; encrypted-media' allowfullscreen></iframe>");
    new_window.document.write("</body></html>");
    // close the document
    new_window.document.close(); 
    }
```

And in the body I have:

```
<a class="audio" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="open_win()">
<img alt="See a demo video (opens in New window)" src="images/demo.jpg" width="120" height="110" /></a>
```

Is it an IE security zones issue, or a coding error?

Comment: Brilliant - You have the answer - Thanks!  Any idea why it's not found (that's surely where function like this should reside?)

Comment: The solution posted seems to have dissappeared ;?   It was to move the function from the head to the body section.

Comment: It should work in either place.

Comment: Is the code inside `<script>...</script>`?

Comment: Well @Barmar - the solution (which seems to have dissappeared from view;?) said that IE11 doesn't find functions in the head section.  So, I moved it to <body> and it now works.   And, happy to relate that yes ... it's within <script> tags.

Comment: I find that difficult to believe. Many web sites put Javascript in the head, they would all break in IE11.

Comment: Can you try this jsfiddle in IE11? http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/1os47xrt/1/

Comment: It "disappeared from view" because he deleted it, probably because he realized it couldn't be right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177687/discussion-between-user801347-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- Are you using strict in your javascript? Maybe if you are using
  strict IE11 does not like you calling a function without passing the
  functions variables.
- Is the javascript in a separate file. Maybe try copying your function right above your html to see if it makes a difference

Comment: Good thinking, but  I have: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">.   And I've tried it with/out passing a variable.

Comment: And the javascript is in the head section of the page.

Comment: did you end up resolving this by removing your javascript from the head section?

Comment: I have tried placing js in the head section from bottom of my page and it works in IE11 where i was having an issue. Thanks.